# Добавление push 0 в конец программы

Tags: ассемблер

Какой смысл в конце программы писать `push 0`, если в ходе работы мы не записывали в стек данные?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле нет никакого смысла В том отношении, как это трактует **@PashaPash**!:)

То, что, например, продемонстрировал **@PashaPash**

```
    push    0
    call    exit
```

это вызов функции `exit` и передачи ей аргумента - кода возврата программы. То есть функция `exit` имеет один параметр, поэтому аргумент ей передается через стек.:)

Что касается возврата значения в операционную систему, и на что ссылается **@PashaPash**, то он возвращается, например, в 16-биттовой системе через регистр `AX`. То есть ваша задача - это занести в регистр `AX` значение 0.

В примере, приведенном **@PashaPash**, эта работа делегируется функции `exit` , которая и заносит в регистр `AX` 0.

На самом деле требование занесения в стек 0 - это требование, если мне память не изменяет, прерывания `int 20h`., которое завершает обычно работу программ, написанных на DOS. так как регистр `CS` должен указывать на `PSP` и 0 - это смещение от начала программы. То есть нужно передать управление по адресу `CS:0`, где расположено `PSP`, которое в свою очередь имеет в этом месте команду возврата в операционную систему.

То есть когда вы занесете в стек 0

```
push 0
```

и затем выполните команду

```
ret
```

то управление перейдет по адресу `CS:0`, где расположен блок `PSP`, у которого со смещением 0 находится прерывание `20h`, которое завершит работу программы.

Answer (score 2):

В конце работы программы вам нужно вернуть exit code. 0 - это удачное завершение. Поэтому обычно программа завершается двумя строчками

```
push 0
<системный вызов для завершения работы программы>
```

0 в это случае является передаваемым системному вызову параметром. Например, в Windows это вызов `ExitProcess(0)`:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.code
program:
    push  0
    call  ExitProcess
end program
```

В чем-то вроде MASM для DOS - это параметр `exit(0)`:

```
.386
.model small,c
.stack 1000h

.data
msg     db "Hello World!",0

.code
includelib MSVCRT
extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
        push    offset msg
        call    printf
        push    0
        call    exit
main endp

end main
```